# How to get parameters values from a URL

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an issue in getting parameters from a URL mentioned below,

`String url = http://example.com/api_callback#access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=enabled&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15551999`

**My code to extract the parameters is as follows:**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parseurl(url); 
Set<String> paramNames = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
```

However, as you can see a "#" in the URL instead of "?" so that's why I am not able to get the parameters Set.

First thing that came to my mind is to replace "#"  with "?" using String.replace method then I thought their might be better solution for this. So if you guys have better solution please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest method:

```
 String string = url.replace("#","?");
 String access_token = Uri.parse(string).getQueryParameter("access_token");

 Log.d("TAG", "AccessToken: " + access_token);
```

Now you can get any parameter from the url just by passing their name.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

'#' is called refrence parameter, Here you can do one of two things either replace the '#' with '?' and process your uri i.e

```
String url = "http://example.com/api_callback#access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=enabled&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15551999";
url = url.Replace("#","?"); //now your URI object to proceed further
```

or other alternative

```
String url = "http://example.com/api_callback#access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=enabled&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15551999";
URL myurl = new URL(url);
String refrence = myurl.getRef(); //returns whatever after '#'
String[][] params = GetParameters(refrence);
```

and the defination for function GetParameters() is following

```
private String[][] GetParameters(String r)
{
   try
    {
       String[] p = r.split("&"); //separate parameters mixed with values
       String[][] data = new String[p.length][2];
       for(int i = 0 ; i<p.length; i++) //iterate whole array
        {
           data[i][0] = p[i].split("=")[0];  //parameter name
           data[i][1] = p[i].split("=")[1];  //parameter value
           data[i][1] = data[i][1].replace("%"," "); //replace % with space character
        }
        return data;  //return result
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

i have not executed and tested the code i am lazy one too so i hope you will accomodate lolz :D

Comment: Your second solution giving `access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=enabled&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=155519991` result. How can I retrieve params values?

Comment: see my edited solution it is addressing your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Uri class in Android to do this; https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.chalklit.in/post.html?chapter=V-Maths-Addition%20&%20Subtraction&post=394");
//Then you can even get a specific element from the query parameters as such;
String chapter = uri.getQueryParameter("chapter");  //will return "V-Maths-Addition "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.chalklit.in/post.html?chapter=V-Maths- Addition%20&%20Subtraction&post=394");
String server = uri.getAuthority();
String path = uri.getPath();
String protocol = uri.getScheme();
Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
```

Then you can even get a **specific element** from the query parameters as such;

```
String chapter = uri.getQueryParameter("key");
```